# Python 2.7 and 2.6 coexist on the same machine

Tags: software-installation, python

I want to follow a guide to install some software on a ReadyNas Duo (sparc).  The guide indicates I need python 2.7, but I already have 2.6 installed.

```
~# which python
/usr/bin/python

~# ls -al /usr/bin/python
lrwx--x--x    1 root     root            9 Jan  5  2012 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6

~# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Mar 16 2011, 19:38:28)
[GCC 3.3.5 (Debian 1:3.3.5-13)] on linux2
```

Other applications I have installed depend on python 2.6, but I'm not sure if they are going to break if I move to 2.7

Is it possible to install 2.7 alongside 2.6 so they coexist?  I assume that applications depend on the default python using `/usr/bin/python` symlink, so ideally 2.7 could sit in `/usr/bin/python2.7` and the new application could just reference that directly?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of running `make install` at the end of the Python build process, run `make altinstall` instead. This will leave `python` alone and create `python2.7` only.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio.  Is the only thing different about altinstall the symlink?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your own version of Python using tools such as [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) and install the various packages you want into this "private installation", rather than try and co-exist with the pre-existing distro's Python.

Answer (score 0):

It will not break anything. For example if I install Python 2.7 in a computer that already have Python 2.6, it will only create a link called `python2.7` and it will not interfere in `python2.6`, because the way you access those two versions are different.